# Python / Selenium, if 'This site can’t be reached' then do something else

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy, request-timed-out

I have a script that tests some proxies and not working proxies will show the page **"This site can’t be reached"**, and If this occurs I want the code to continue and try again with a different proxy, but selenium stays stuck on the "This site can’t be reached" page.

I tried a `try/exept` clause but selenium still stays on the error page, I also tried `except TimeoutError`, but still stuck.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
import time

proxy_ip_port = 'ip:port'

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

# replace 'your_absolute_path' with your chrome binary absolute path
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=capabilities)

try:
    driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/signup/phone-or-email/email')
except TimeoutError:
    print("Proxy: ", proxy_ip_port, "invalid")
```

Output:

```html
C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\tkinter\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/fkahd/PycharmProjects/tkinter/proxy2.py
C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\tkinter\proxy2.py:17: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=capabilities)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

"This site can’t be reached" page:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What actual error is raised by the `driver.get()` call?  Obviously it isn't `TimeoutError`, because you're catching that.

Comment: @JohnGordon when I run the script, the driver tries to get the site trough the proxy mentionned in `ip_port` but fails and shows the "This site can’t be reached" page, and the process finishes with exit code 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the page load timeout value, and catch the TimeoutException type.

I was able to catch a failure with the generalized exception handling (I entered a loopback proxy for completeness...):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



proxy_ip_port = '10.27.0.0:80'

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

# replace 'your_absolute_path' with your chrome binary absolute path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
try:
    driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/signup/phone-or-email/email')
except TimeoutException:
    print("Proxy: ", proxy_ip_port, "invalid")
```

Comment: The code still doesn't print ("Proxy: ", proxy_ip_port, "invalid") and just exits with code 0

Comment: Are you successful in reaching the page?

Comment: No, that's the problem, I am getting 'site cand't be reached' and therefore want to print print("Proxy: ", proxy_ip_port, "invalid")

Comment: ah. I got ya....one sec.

Comment: How does that work? it won't function if you specify a page timeout value that is greater than the brower's timeout value; for that I am afraid you will have to look for a known element on the page; and timeout from there.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with `driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)` Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243010/discussion-between-shawn-ramirez-and-xtekky).